# R filter using a condition based on a vector and keeping missing values

Tags: r, datatable, filtering, subset, data-manipulation

I have a datatable that I want to filter, based on values contained on a vector.
For instant, I have values given several countries, and a desired list of countries.

I usually use the following :

```
library(tidyverse)
library(datatable)
mwe <- data.table(
  c("France","UnitedStates","Germany","UnitedKingrom","Italy"),
  rnorm(5,2,1)
)

EuroZone = c("Germany","France","Italy","Spain")


mwe_filtered <- mwe %>%
  .[V1 %in% EuroZone,]

mwe_filtered
        V1        V2
1:  France 3.2136065
2: Germany 2.2208924
3:   Italy 0.3714978
```

And it is usually enough as I have all the countries in the database I want to filter.
This time however I lack Spain in my original dataset.

My desired output would signal that and therefore be :

```
mwe_filtered_desired
        V1        V2
1:  France 3.2136065
2: Germany 2.2208924
3:   Italy 0.3714978
4:   Spain        NA
```

I think I can achieve that by merging, but this would complicated the usability a bit.
Is there a better way to achieve that ?

Answer (score 1):

Not complicated at all using `merge`.

```
merge(mwe, data.frame(V1=EuroZone), all.y=T)
#         V1        V2
# 1:  France 0.8334164
# 2: Germany 0.3868958
# 3:   Italy 1.7665252
# 4:   Spain        NA
```

Answer (score 0):

I think merging is the best way to do it, simply with data.table

```r
merge(mwe, data.table(V1 = EuroZone), on = "V1", all = TRUE)
```